# Is there any way to bind different query string pertaining to same field of @ModelAttribute in @Controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

```
Class ExampleModel {
      private String product;
}

@RequestMapping("/products")
public getProducts( @ModelAttribute ExampleModel model){
}
```

* What I want is to populate model with product class member if I hit the following REST end points:

```
/products?product=xyz  or /products?prodName=xyz or /products?prod=xyz
```

*